# How to select_related on an inherited table

Tags: python, django

I have a model that represents a Post model in django and one called NewsArticle which inherits from it. I also have a table of likes that maps a user's like to a Post. How can I get all NewsArticles with their corresponding like status?

Here are the models I have:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=200)
    content = TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class NewsArticle(Post):
    link = URLField(default='')
    external_id = CharField(unique=True,
                            max_length=50, help_text='The ID of the news article from the source')
    source = CharField(max_length=15, help_text='Name of source website')

class Like(models.Model):
    LIKE_CHOICES = [('L', 'Like'), ('D', 'Dislike')]

    user = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='post')
    state = CharField(default='L', max_length=1, choices=LIKE_CHOICES)
    created_at = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_state_display()
```

The query I'm trying should select from NewsArticle and have the state of the like of a user or None if no mapping exists. I tried to `select_related('post_ptr')` but that just added the post ID in the queryset which I don't really know how to use.

Comment: Your `Like` and `NewArticle` models are not connected. When you inherit from another table means that it will use the same fields and the same methods, but it doesn't create a connection between the tables.

Comment: Oh I see. Can I select posts that are newsarticles? and then get the likes on them?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Like -> NewsArticle
for like in Like.objects.select_related('post__newsarticle'):
    like.post.newsarticle
# NewsArticles -> Likes
for article in NewsArticle.objects.prefetch_related('post_ptr__like_set'):
    for like in article.post_ptr.like_set.all():
        like.user
        like.state
# NewsArticle -> Likes
article = NewsArticle.objects.prefetch_related('post_ptr__like_set').get(id=1)  # use your id
for like in article.post_ptr.like_set.all():
    like.user
    like.state
```

The above may be different depending on if `related_name` is set

`selected_related`/`prefetch_related` are for reducing duplicate queries, they are not required to access data. The above code will work without them.

Comment: I believe I'd need your second query for what I want to do but wouldn't this hit the database once for every like?

Comment: That's what select_related/prefetch_related for for, they grab the associated data ahead of time.

Comment: If you have 3 news articles and 2 likes on each one, how many queries will your second code fragment execute?

Comment: It should only do 2-3. You can install django-debug-toolbar which allows you to view how many queries a view is running. Then you can compare the before/after of using select/prefetch related.